# Typescript typing for spread operator

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi I have a project where there is a collection of project data and it uses a spread for the props. I wanted to make this more correctly typed in typescript. Before I just had props: any and no errors. The main page has this code:

```
{projectInformation.map(project => (
      <div key={project.id} className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 mb-4">
        <Project {...project} />
      </div>
    ))}
```

And then in the project component I have this to start:

```
const Project = (props: {
  projectTitle: string,
  projectDescription: string,
  codeUrl: string,
  deployedLink: string,
  projectThumbnail: string,
  projectThumbnailAlt: string,
  hasLiveDemo: boolean,
  externalLink: boolean,
  hasPublicGithubPage: boolean  
}) => {
```

With that I have no errors on the project component, but on the main page that maps projects I see the below error when hovering over the <Project {...project} />

```
Type '{ id: number; projectTitle: string; projectDescription: string; codeUrl: string; deployedLink: string; projectThumbnail: string; projectThumbnailAlt: string; hasLiveDemo: boolean; externalLink: boolean; hasPublicGithubPage: boolean; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { projectTitle: string; projectDescription: string; codeUrl: string; deployedLink: string; projectThumbnail: string; projectThumbnailAlt: string; hasLiveDemo: boolean; externalLink: boolean; hasPublicGithubPage: boolean; }'.
  Type '{ id: number; projectTitle: string; projectDescription: string; codeUrl: string; deployedLink: string; projectThumbnail: string; projectThumbnailAlt: string; hasLiveDemo: boolean; hasPublicGithubPage: boolean; externalLink?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ projectTitle: string; projectDescription: string; codeUrl: string; deployedLink: string; projectThumbnail: string; projectThumbnailAlt: string; hasLiveDemo: boolean; externalLink: boolean; hasPublicGithubPage: boolean; }'.
    Types of property 'externalLink' are incompatible.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: `externalLink` is optional in your `project`, but it's not optional in the `Project`.

Comment: Ah thank you. I was a bit confused and it turned out that for just one project I had forgotten to put an "externalLink" for that one. Fixing that made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `externalLink?: boolean` property in a `project` item is [optional (`?`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) which means it can be assigned a `boolean` or `undefined`. Therefore TypeScript complains that a possibly `undefined` value is not assignable to type `boolean` in the `props` of your `Project` component.

In order to get rid of the compiler error either define `externalLink` in `props` optionally too or make sure `externalLink` is required in your `projectInformation` array.